# Can't connect to the extensions Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am also not able to download "Salesforce Extension Pack", getting error "We can not connect to extension market place this time".
Please help me on this.

**Help -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Network**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh9Fl.png)

**To confirm its a DNS issue check if you can access this page** https://ms-python.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/ms-python/python/2019.8.29288/1565127378610/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Icons.Default,

*Yes I am able to open the link and see the image.*

**Help -> Toggle Developer Tools -> Console**

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT workbench.desktop.main.js:1642 ERR net::ERR_TIMED_OUT: Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:2623:21) at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:203:13) marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT 2workbench.desktop.main.js:6668 Error querying extensions gallery Canceled (anonymous) @ workbench.desktop.main.js:6668 workbench.desktop.main.js:6668 Error querying extensions gallery XHR timeout: undefinedms (anonymous) @ workbench.desktop.main.js:6668 marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

**View -> Command Pallette... -> Toggle Shared Process -> Console**

```
2az764295.vo.msecnd.net/extensions/marketplace.json:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

**Log (shared)**

```
[2020-06-10 11:50:32.933] [sharedprocess] [info] main {"machineId":"48fe33e62508cacf66f14a567d671e76e5f2563e2186c3f7681e1ce13e22add6","windowId":2} [2020-06-10 11:51:13.033] [sharedprocess] [info] Starting to clean up unused language packs.
```

**log(window)**

```
[2020-06-10 11:51:03.595] [renderer1] [error] net::ERR_TIMED_OUT: Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:2623:21) at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:203:13)
```